# removing element from array on button click in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove an element from an array on button click in angular

```
 <div
       class="example-box"
        *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>
        {{item}} 
           <div>*ngFor="let newTask of todo; index as i"
          <button class="remove" mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="onDeleteTask(i)">X</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

ts

```
  onDeleteTask(index: number) {
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.todo.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you specify what issue you faced in the question?

Comment: Meanwhile, `<div>*ngFor="let newTask of todo; index as i"` is wrong. Have to be `<div *ngFor="let newTask of todo; index as i">`.

Comment: @YongShun thank you so much that fixed it<3 i didn't notice ;.;

Answer (score -1):

I gues that you say that your code is wrong by this:

```
<div>*ngFor="let newTask of todo; index as i"
```

It should be:

```
<div *ngFor="let newTask of todo; index as i">
```

But I guess that what you really want to get is a single button for every row:

```
<div>
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <div
  class="example-box"
   *ngFor="let item of todo; index as i" cdkDrag>
   {{item}}     
     <button class="remove" mat-flat-button color="warn" (click)="onDeleteTask(i)">X</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Link to demo with code working](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-firefly-o78o7?file=/src/app/app.component.html:68-324)

Answer (score -1):

I assume your view (HTML) won't change after you remove the item, right?
You need to force the DOM to re-render itself. You can simply do this:

add `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` to `constructor`

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

then you should update your `onDeleteTask` function into this:

```
onDeleteTask(index: number) {
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.todo.splice(index, 1);
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); // this forces your html to render changes
    }
}
```